# php sql date time comparison

Tags: php, date

I have a last_notified column on my MySQL table, data type `DATETIME`
I want to either only select the rows where last_notified is more than *n* seconds old, or compare the last_notified value from the db in php.

I have tried messing around with the date object.

```
$d = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // current date and time
$dd = date('2011-09-08 10:21:34'); // this is the format used in mysql.
```

I know I cannot just compare them, and i'm unaware of how to add time to the date object. I have seen examples of people using something along the lines of

```
$t = explode(" ",$dd);
date($dd, strtotime('+30 minutes', strtotime($t[1])));
```

but that doesn't work . I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sql like this:

`SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE last_notified < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL n SECOND)`

Comment: nice xdazz! you beat me to the punch!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your first snippet and date mask in first line

```
Y-m-d H:m:s
```

you use `m` mask twice, so it means there will be month instead of minutes.
you should use `i` mask to specify the minutes

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE last_notified < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL n SECOND)
```